# 'Convert to edit' option in mod menu looks weird on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, mobile-safari

The 'convert to edit' option in the mod menu for answers looks ... weird ... when viewed in Safari on an iPhone. The font size is much smaller than the other options:

[image]

Note that the other disabled option ('move comments to chat') has the same font size as the enabled options.

In case it matters, it's an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 12.3.1, I'm using full site mode (responsive design) and the screenshot was taken in landscape orientation.

Comment: Following the recent revamp to the mod tools, is this still an issue today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sonic guessed correctly in the comments, this has been solved with the [New mod-menu design rolling out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332324/295232):

[image]

However, that update might have introduced [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368259/295232)...