# What do the moderator tools and pages look like?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators

I am a fan of Stack Overflow, and I think the moderator system is brilliant. Although I am not a moderator, I am still very curious about what a moderator's life looks like. In particular, could I have some screenshots of the moderator pages?

I have read the documents in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), but cannot see much.

Comment: "what a moderator's life looks like" A lot of routine...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some tools will not be shared with the general public, because how they are implemented (or even their mere existence) will make them less effective.

That said, by [searching on this site for posts tagged [moderator-tools] and containing the word 'announcement'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmoderator-tools%5D+announcement) you can get a basic idea of some of the tools. Here are some hits with screenshots:

- [Moderator Flag Dashboard soft launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330171/moderator-flag-dashboard-soft-launch)

> [image]

- [New mod-menu design rolling out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332324/new-mod-menu-design-rolling-out)

> [image]

Another option, if you have more time, is to try [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmoderator-tools%5D+url%3Astack.imgur.com) which returns (almost) all posts tagged [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) with images in them.