# Markdown not properly rendered in 'Convert to edit' mod action description

Tags: bug, markdown, moderator-tools

The description of the mod action 'Convert to edit' contains Markdown which is not rendered:

> **by the asker**

[image]

Another option, 'Lock', does contain a rendered link, so it's not a question of the mod menu not supporting markup at all.